# Where and how should I keep Client Secret?

Tags: github, oauth-2.0, github-api

For OAuth authorization through applications, you must specify the `clientID` and `clientSecret`. This is necessary so that GitHub can identify my application and remove some restrictions.

I registered my application and got the `id` and `secret`, but! it is not clear where to keep `Secret`, many people do **not recommend** storing it in the **source code, which is also public**. I do not have a server, I do not know where to store it.

I write on C# + UWP.

Comment: Does UWP support environment variables?

Comment: @osowskit of course.

Comment: Do any of the top three results help point you in the right direction : https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=uwp+api+key

Comment: Not one option came up. In general, everything is clear, can not be stored on the client. It is not clear why, because of such a bullshit, does OAuth still exist? @osowskit

Comment: It may be useful to rethink "necessary so that GitHub can identify my application and remove some restrictions". Can you do this as a GitHub App running remotely

Answer (score 0):

I know you are C# and Universal Windows Platform (UWP), but thought I would post this, since it may help.

My Git-Captain node.js project stands up a server that does calls to the GitHub API. In the [GitHub Git-Captain project](https://github.com/ConfusedDeer/Git-Captain) readme, I explain to store the client_secret and client_id on the server.

I store the client_secret and client_id on the server in a ".env" file on the "controllers" directory (Node.js controller).

The idea with the .env files is that when the node.js server starts it loads environment variables from a .env file, which can be accessed from the process.env node.js property.

The solution may be too much for what you are trying to do, but checkout the project and if you can setup a Node.js server on a windows server than you can modify it to do whatever you need.

In the coming months I'm going push the Linux Server instructions and we know a Linux server running on AWS is dirt cheap and GitHub is also free.

If interested, checkout the [demo](https://youtu.be/LOLxImi5t7w) on YouTube.